# Excel sheet exported from datatables opens in protected view

Tags: excel, datatables

When I use the export function provided in datatables to download data as excel sheet, then open it in my MS Excel program, the sheet opens in protected view, with a warning about file being originated form internet and potentially dangerous.

This happens on the example on the datatable website - https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export

Also, same when I am using the feature in my own intranet infrastructure.

Any suggestions to fix the problem ?

Comment: have you tried opening the file you downloaded from datatables.net?

Comment: Goto `Excel` --> `File` --> `Options` --> `Trust Center` --> `Click on Trust Center Settings...` --> `Select Protected View` and change the settings to your preferences. If you want to ensure that a certain site is not considered `Internet` and as such files from this source will be trusted and considered to be "from the Intranet" instead then you do so in the `Trusted Locations` tab (adding a certain path or web-address).

Comment: Any Excel file downloaded from Internet will have the protected flag enabled. You can change this behavior only from your browser settings as Ralph suggested. But it will be just for you...

Comment: Thanks guys, but I don't have privileges to change Trust Center settings, also the problem occurs when the file is being fetched from intranet as well. I even went from using a cdn to having the library hosted locally, and still getting the same warning.